# Android SplashScreen customization not working when targetSdk is 34

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am trying to change the Splash Screen on Android 13 and up. My targetSdk is 34. I am using Jetpack Compose. The problem is that it does not matter if I follow [this tutorial from Google exactly step by step](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen), the color will always be white/black (depending on dark mode), and the icon is always the launcher icon.
I tried with multiple different versions of ***androidx.core:core-splashscreen***

**styles.xml**

```
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/custom_svg_icon</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.App</item>
    </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
```

I tried changing colors, and icons, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 2 different variants of themes.xml for light and dark mode. To make 2nd themes.xml follow these steps:

right click values -> new -> values resource file

A window will open, enter the file name "themes" and select night qualifier, and click ok.

Open both `themes.xml` files and add this item in style:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">Your Color</item
```

Make sure the style parent is valid (play around with it) for example:

```
"android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar" for dark action bar 
"android:Theme.Material.Light" for light
```

Make sure the correct theme is mentioned in `androidmanifest.xml`